# R logit model variable choice

Tags: r

I have a dataset where each household has an observation for each of five power generation methods (so each household appears 5 times). There is a dummy variable marking which method they use, so a sample household might look like --

```
hh_id  choice     choice_dummy  
1      Grid        0
1      Diesel      0
1      Ownsolar    1
1      Solargrid   0
1      None        0
```

I have some other variables (price, avail, load, peakhours) that I need to run in a logit model to see what is influencing the decision to pick a particular choice. I know to use glm() for this, but I'm unsure of what to put in for the dependent variable. "Choice" doesn't actually capture the decision that was made, because "choice_dummy" actually marks the decision, but "choice_dummy" by itself doesn't give any information.

I can't merely filter for choice_dummy being 1 because I will lose the values for all the other variables by doing that. Does anyone know how I would go about running a logit model that relates the probability of each household choosing an energy source to the variables "price," "avail," "load," and "peakhours", ideally with code?

Comment: I looks like you have multinomial choice data, so you need to fit a multinomial or conditional logit model. For example with the gmnl or mlogit package. Mlogit has a vignette that might help you getting started (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/e1mlogit.html). If you post a repex using the `dput` function I could offer more specific help.

Comment: Consider multinomial logistic regression? Define 'power_choice' where choice is one of the 5 power options and choice_dummy = 1. Recode predictor variables that way, then specify the regression model.

Comment: #TJ87 
This seems like the way I need to go, but I'm having trouble coming up with how I'd go about defining 'power_choice' with mutate. I'm not entirely clear on how I'd go about mutating a new column on two conditions in that manner. Is there any chance you could whip up that line?

Comment: You'll probably want to transform your data first from long (multiple lines per hh_id) to wide (1 line per hh_id) using reshape::cast or reshape2::dcast. Then coding 'power_choice', etc. should be easier to do. I will try to follow up later.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to OP's comment 5/22/20:

```
hh_id<-c("1","1","1","1","1")
choice <- c("Grid","Diesel","Ownsolar","Solargrid","None")
choice_dummy <- c("0","0","1","0","0")
df <- data.frame(hh_id,choice,choice_dummy)

library(reshape2)

df2 <- dcast(df, hh_id ~ choice)

df2$power_choice <- ifelse(df2$Grid==1,"Grid",
ifelse(df2$Diesel==1,"Diesel",
ifelse(df2$Ownsolar==1,"Ownsolar",
ifelse(df2$Solargrid==1,"Solargrid",
ifelse(df2$None==1,"None",NA)))))
```